# How does one measure resource contention between Virtualized Systems/VMs on the same Host?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization

On numerous occasions I have faced the question whether the virtual machine I am on is being affected by other VMs running on the same VM host. I understand that even in a perfect scenario where neither CPU nor RAM nor Disk have been over-provisioned there will be some effects on sibling VMs on the same host.

Are there any proven methods of measuring resource contention from within a Virtual Machine? What is a good approach?

I have in the past measured run time of standardized tasks(eg. compiling GCC or encoding video) between different VMs, but the results vary even when I control the load on all other VMs on the same system.

I should mention all these systems are Linux based.

Edit: Let's assume I do not have direct access to the host, only the VMs

Comment: Do you have access to the VM Host ?

Comment: Yes and No, In some scenarios I would, but I would really like to be able to judge the impact when I do not have access to the host. Such as in a public could for example.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to determine that from a guest. See my answer for things you can do on a host though.

Comment: I know it's not easy, but comparing performance benchmarks between two VMs on separate hosts gives you a general idea of contention. For example, comparing the CPU side, say I compile GCC on two VMs and on one it takes 5 mins on the other 10 mins. That means there is less contention on the first one than on the second one. Now if I have a baseline, say I compile GCC on bare metal and it takes 4 minutes, I can put the performance of the two VMs in perspective relative to a real CPU minute.

Answer (score 1):

For CPU contentions, you can measure the [CPU Steal Time](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2013/07/25/understanding-cpu-steal-time-when-should-you-be-worried). From the linked article:

> Steal time is the percentage of time a virtual CPU waits for a real CPU while the hypervisor is servicing another virtual processor.

Comment: can reporting of this metric to a guest be muffled in KVM/QEMU settings?

Answer (score 0):

VMWare have a nice doco on determining resource contention - http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2001003

Assuming you're using 5.1 -

1. **CPU**
   Check esxtop on the command line
   Load Average of 1 means that the CPUs are fully utilised.
   Ready % should be under 5%
2. **Memory**
   Check esxtop on the command line
   Check the MEM overcommit value
   Minus 1 from the MEM overcommit value, if the field ends up with 0 then you're fine.
   Otherwise if it's above 0 then you're overcommiting RAM
3. **Disk**
   Check esxtop on the command line
   See if DAVG latency time is higher than 5 seconds

Comment: I have updated the question, I am looking for a method that is not hypervisor specific nor requires access to the Host